# How do I center an image while zooming?

Tags: javascript, zooming, center

So I need the image to center after having zoomed in, I cannot use any Jquerys
right now it all zooms in moving right and overlays but the image to the far right is getting cut off by the end of the browser screen

```
<script>
var target;     //global container for currently clicked div
var timer;
var tick = 40;
var diffw = 341;
var diffh = 235;
var trans = 0.5; //opacity 
var zoomed = false; //boolean, can only be true or false


function startAnimation(divname) {
    target = divname; 
    if (zoomed==false)  {
        timer = setInterval("zoomPhotoIn()",tick); 
    }else {
        timer = setInterval("zoomPhotoOut()",tick); 

    }
}

function zoomPhotoIn()  {
    trans += 0.02;
    diffw += 15;
    diffh += 10;

    document.getElementById(target).style.opacity = trans;
    document.getElementById(target).style.width = diffw+"px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.height = diffh+"px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.zIndex = 5;

    if(diffw >= 700)    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        zoomed = true;
    }
}

function zoomPhotoOut() {
    trans -= 0.02;
    diffw -= 15;
    diffh -= 10;

    document.getElementById(target).style.opacity = trans;
    document.getElementById(target).style.width = diffw+"px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.height = diffh+"px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.zIndex = 1;

    if(diffw <= 341)    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        zoomed = false;
    }

}

</script>
```

Comment: `top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:-height/2;margin-left:-width/2;` with width and height being the values related to the image/its container.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically @Shmiddty's comment in answer form.

These edits are assuming that the image has a `position` that's not static and has `top:50%` and `left:50%`:

```
<script>
var target;     //global container for currently clicked div
var timer;
var tick = 40;
var diffw = 341;
var diffh = 235;
var trans = 0.5; //opacity 
var zoomed = false; //boolean, can only be true or false


function startAnimation(divname) {
    target = divname; 
    if (zoomed==false)  {
        timer = setInterval("zoomPhotoIn()",tick); 
    }else {
        timer = setInterval("zoomPhotoOut()",tick); 

    }
}

function zoomPhotoIn()  {
    trans += 0.02;
    diffw += 15;
    diffh += 10;

    document.getElementById(target).style.opacity = trans;
    document.getElementById(target).style.width = diffw+"px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.height = diffh+"px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.zIndex = 5;
    document.getElementById(target).style.marginLeft = (diffw/2) + "px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.marginTop = (diffh/2) + "px";

    if(diffw >= 700)    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        zoomed = true;
    }
}

function zoomPhotoOut() {
    trans -= 0.02;
    diffw -= 15;
    diffh -= 10;

    document.getElementById(target).style.opacity = trans;
    document.getElementById(target).style.width = diffw+"px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.height = diffh+"px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.zIndex = 1;
    document.getElementById(target).style.marginLeft = (diffw/2) + "px";
    document.getElementById(target).style.marginTop = (diffh/2) + "px";

    if(diffw <= 341)    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        zoomed = false;
    }

}

</script>
```

Comment: forgot to mention that I am using the 1140 grid system as it part of my assignment. Thanks for the help but if there any way you could help me with that, that would be awesome. I have each image in a "fourcol" div and thats how they are placed on my design.